# Where should i put a do while bool is true

Tags: c++

I wrote a program that outputs the name equivalent of a numerical grade the user wrote into the console.

> 1 being FAIL
>
> 2 being SATISFACTORY
>
> 3 being GOOD
>
> 4 being VERY GOOD
>
> 5 being EXCELLENT

Now I would like to ask the user does he want to continue inputting the grades AFTER the first one runs,

e.g

input grade
-> 5
Excellent
Would you like to continue inputting grades? 1 - yes/ 0 -no

I'm clueless where to put the do while bool is true..

```
int main()
{
    int grade;


        do
        {
            cout << "input your grade: \n";
            cin >> grade;

            if (grade < 1 || grade > 5)
            {
                cout << "input grade again!\n";
            }



        } while (grade < 1 || grade > 5);



        switch (grade)
        {
        case 1:
            cout << "fail\n";
            break;

        case 2:
            cout << "satisfactory\n";
            break;

        case 3:
            cout << "good\n";
            break;

        case 4:
            cout << "very good\n";
            break;

        case 5:
            cout << "excellent\n";
            break;



        }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need another **do-while statement** to have a repeated process. I've initialized a `char` variable named `userChoice` *(always make the initialization to avoid undefined behaviors and hard to track errors)* to check in every iteration what user wants *(to continue or to end the program)*.

```
//previous codes...
char userChoice = 'n';
do{
    // previous codes which you want to be repeated
    std::cout << "\nDo you want to continue ? (y = Yes, n = No ) "; // ask the user to continue or to end
    std::cin >> userChoice; // store user's input in the userChoice variable

}while(userChoice); // if user's input is 'y' then continue with next iteration
//rest of the code...
```

Also, [Why is "using namespace std" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)